# @Media Queries for IE9 Desktop Browser

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, media-queries

I'm having trouble with @media queries for IE9 Desktop. I've created a site that when someone resizes their browser down, the entire layout changes based on the "screen" size. The entire layout changes to fit the screen size.

However, when it comes to IE9 on the Desktop, nothing happens. the Original layout (built for 1024 resolution) appears. so anyone with say a 768 screen size (or lower), sees the layout "bleed" over. IT doesn't change for them.

the site WORKS in Chorme, Firefox and even Opera, but not in IE9 Desktop

Here are my call outs:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px){
bunch of settings
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px){
bunch of settings
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
bunch of settings
}
```

^^^ these are not being recognized by IE9 when I resize the browser down.

Please help.

Comment: I am also having this problem. The issue isn't IE9 not being able to understand media queries - it does. It just doesn't re-apply the rules when the browser is resized without refreshing the window.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 media queries are supported as of IE9, so your media queries should work. My immediate guess would be you have [compatibility view](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie-9/features/compatibility-view) turned on, switch it off and your media queries should work.

---

I updated your final media query to:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    bunch of settings
}
```

my guess is when you resize your ie9 browser, it never reaches a maximum width of 320..it is stuck somewhere between 320 and 480 so which means none of your media query settings are met - hence it defaults to the 1024 one. Changing the maximum width to just one below the minimum of your previous viewport (480-1 = 479), will solve this problem.

Either that, or there must be some problems in your rules inside the queries that ie9 fails to recognize but the other browsers have no problem with.

Comment: I've tested in IE9 with both Compatibility view on and off. The layout doesn't change when I change the size of the browser on the desktop.

Comment: very strange, i put something together on jsFiddle and tested on ie9 and it works properly - note the change in my answer though because i did make one difference to your media query..you can also check the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/435Cz/3/embedded/result/

Answer (score -1):

IE9 does support media queries. Switch the order round and they should work.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
   bunch of settings
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px){
   bunch of settings
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px){
   bunch of settings
}
```

Comment: I did this in the CSS file and this also didn't solve the issue. The layout doesn't change when I re-size the browser down.

Comment: ARe you using the html5 doctype?